# Trying to use numpy in intellij, But it won't work

Tags: python, numpy, intellij-idea

[I tried the command in my cmd and this is what is said, I don't really know what it means though, and I still can't use NumPy in IntelliJ.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfIOb.png)[[This is the whole thing, it says NumPy isn't there even though I find it in the external libraries when I go through them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOVDx.png)]

Comment: On command prompt try some version of `python3.9 -m pip install numpy`. It is possible you have multiple versions of Python

Comment: Please post the whole coommand and error as a text

Comment: @pcmm23 Find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your IDE (wherever you're running your Python program) runs in the same environment that the one where you install your packages. It appears like you have 2 environments: One with "native Python" installed in your machine (where your program runs), and an Anaconda environment (where you installed numpy).

I recommend you stick with Anaconda and use it only. In your Start Menu, search for "Anaconda Prompt". There you can install any packages you want, but it seems numpy is already installed. Then you can type, for example, `code` to open VS Code, or `jupyter notebook` to run Jupyter. Or type `python` and start coding.

But if you really want to use a program outside Anaconda environment, then you have to install your packages in your "native Python" environment. You can do such using the Windows cmd or PowerShell, instead of Anaconda Prompt.